# Excel Macro to create school reports

Tags: excel, vba, macros, basic

hi everyone i need your help, i'm a school teacher with very minor knowledge of excel macros. I've created an excel worksheet with a table includes student names and lesson scores, i need a macro to create report for every student (every row of table) to a template that i created as report template

I've been looking so hard to find any tips or help on internet but no luck so far.

I've tried searching, and found a few examples, but none quite fit..such as this one.. create macro that will convert excel rows from single sheet to new sheets ..or this one.. Excel Macro that saves data inputted from one sheet onto successive rows in another sheet
Thank you so much

Comment: Elaborate your question please. Tell us what exactly you want. Also, add a screenshot of your file if possible.

Comment: So you want to go from one sheet to many sheets or from many sheets to one sheet? Sorry, it's not clear thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try and customize as you need, this code:
(my main table header is: student_id | name | surname | group)

```
Sub gen_reports()

Set ref_col = Application.Selection
Set ref_col = Application.InputBox("Select ID col of main table", xTitleId, ref_col.Address, Type:=8) ' select students from student_id col

For Each C In ref_col
    Worksheets.Add.Name = C.Offset(0, 1) ' create a sheet for each student
   ActiveSheet.Select
   Range("a1").Value = "Report for " & C.Offset(0, 1) & " " & C.Offset(0, 2) & " / " & C.Offset(0, 3) ' fill each sheet with elements from each student

Next
End Sub
```

you can format the report(student's sheet) as you need, programatically. ex: Range("a1").Font.ColorIndex = 44   etc